# Executing mysql commands from an external sql file in terminal

Tags: mysql, bash

I am trying to execute mysql from an external file and this is what I am doing:

`mysql -u "root" -p < "init.sql"` #calling this in terminal

Tried something like this:

init.sql contents:

```
 CREATE USER 'myuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

but this ends up in: ERROR 1396 (HY000) at line 5: Operation CREATE USER failed for 'myuser'@'localhost'

When read a post that it is advised to first drop the user:

init.sql contents:

```
DROP USER 'myuser'@'localhost';

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

CREATE USER 'myuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

but I get an error: ERROR 1396 (HY000) at line 3: Operation DROP USER failed for 'myuser'@'localhost'

which is normal as the user does not exist. This workflow works perfectly if I just paste these in command line, but not through bash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need an external file, rather use `bash` [here-docs](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) for this.

```
mysql -u "root" -p <<EOF
DROP USER 'myuser'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
CREATE USER 'myuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
EOF
```